# Extract version string from text file with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to pull the version # out of a Vim script that might look something like:

```
 " some header blah blah
 " Version: 0.1
 [a bunch of code]
 " Version: fake--use only the first version
```

The expected output is `0.1`. If a Version # doesn't exist, it should return the empty string or something like that.

I'm new to Powershell, so this is what I have so far:

```
Get-Content somescript.vim -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-String '^" Version: (.*)' | 
    select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Matches |
    select -ExpandProperty Groups |
    select -Index 1 |
    select -ExpandProperty Value
```

It's just that it feels... kind of verbose. For comparison, here's my *nix version:

```
perl -ne '/^" Version: (.*)/ && do { print "$1\n"; exit }' somescript.vim 2>/dev/null
```

*Or you could write a similarly concise `awk` script*

Is there any hope for my Windows version being as concise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell everything is an object, so you can access properties (and properties of properties) using the dot operator just like you can in most object based languages.

```
$matches = Get-Content somescript.vim -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-String '^" Version: (.*)'

if ($matches)
{
    $matches[0].Matches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course, just use an intermediate result. Hadn't thought of it, but totally obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a terser approach using only built-ins, but having a little more confidence now in Powershell, I think I'd simply refactor out the group matching code:

```
filter Select-MatchingGroupValue($groupNum) {
    if (! $groupNum) {
        $groupNum = 0
    }
    select -InputObject $_ -ExpandProperty Matches |
        select -ExpandProperty Groups |
        select -Index $groupNum |
        select -ExpandProperty Value
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
Get-Content .\somescript.vim -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-String '^" Version: (.*)' |
    select -First 1 |
    Select-MatchingGroupValue 1
```

In the end, you haven't saved that many lines, but refactoring out the tedious expansions of `Matches`, `Groups`, and `Value` makes the resulting code much clearer IMO.